# I'm having issues setting up a container div keeping text within the container div

Tags: html, css

For some reason the body tag settings spill into the container div and text in the p tag goes out of the container div boundaries. I don't know why. Adding another div and applying the settings there fixed the issue, but I wanted the settings to apply to the container div.

I was expecting a centered green div with the placeholder text in it aligned like the rest of the elements, and a grey background using the body tag. How can I solve this problem?

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  color: #A4A7A5;
}

div #container {
  color: #63EC91;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: Roboto;
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: lightgrey;
  padding: 20px;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#container .FCR {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: Roboto, Arial;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-family: Roboto, Arial;
}

h1 {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: Roboto, Arial;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="pocetna1.html">Pocetna</a></li>
    <li><a href="onama1.html">O nama</a></li>
    <li><a href="kontakti1.html">Kontakti</a></li>
    <li><a href="galerija1.html">Galerija</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h1>Meni stranica</h1>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <p class="FCR"> FCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCR</p>
</div>
```

Comment: please put ur code on sandbox (https://codesandbox.io) and put ur codesandbox link here. we need ro run ur code.

Comment: @HoseinSoleymani No. Code belong in the question, not on a third party site. Links rot. Plus, SO has an executable snippet feature that can do what the third party sites do anyway

Comment: Have you tried applying overflow: hidden; to the #container?

Answer (score 0):

I think ur problem is about

```
FCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCRCR
```

text that u put inside of p tag.
default browser split the word and put their into new line when there is any space (" ") between words BTW I guess u can use word-wrap: break-word to change this behavior.
Also u can use overflow property to prevent this but it's not a good solution.

Comment: I removed the width attribute of the fcr div and it worked. I will keep your suggestion in mind as well, thanks.